# I'm trying put this reference below the graph

Tags: pgfplots, floats, captions

I'm trying put this reference below the graph, also I want this figure a little smaller, how can I do this?
my code is:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            [xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$]
            \addplot3[surf,domain=-2:2,domain y=-2:2]
            {(2-x^2-y^2)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{}
\label{compression}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear, what you after: centering image or move caption to the left border of text. Let assume, that image should be centered:

a) Centering of Image:

- Below image is caption ...
- Caption is usually horizontally centered (except if you somewhere in document determine otherwise)
- Image is not horizontally centered in float. That it be, you need add `\centering` after `\begin{figure}` (see MWE below).

b) Image size

- it can be determined on two ways:

  - by determining width of image by adding `width=<desired width>` to `axis` options (as is done in the first example),
  - by scaling od `tikzpicture` as is done in the second example)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=0.5\linewidth,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$
            ]
\addplot3[surf,domain=-2:2,domain y=-2:2]
{(2-x^2-y^2)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{first example}
    
\bigskip
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$
            ]
\addplot3[surf,domain=-2:2,domain y=-2:2]
{(2-x^2-y^2)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{second example}
\label{compression}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Comment: Well, if I need put a red point in the graph at maximun value, how can I do this? @zarko

Comment: Dear @TheMartian, new problem, new question :-). This is not a forum but Q&A site, your problems had to be visible to all member of site ... BTW, please inform me, which od suggested solution is what you after. And if one of them solve problem stated in question, please consider to upvote and even accept answer.